# Ordering Tuple in Descending Order C#

Tags: c#, sorting, tuples

I have recently started to learn C#, and have a tuple which holds six ints. Is there any function I could use that sorts the tuple into descending order--for instance:

Tuple <5,4,3,3,7,8>
Becomes
Tuple <8,7,5,4,3,3>

Comment: You're using the wrong tool. You want to use a collection type, like a list or an array.

Comment: And no, there is nothing built into the language or runtime for this precisely because you're using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuples are just holders of different values - a bag to keep them together. Tuples are not lists and are therefore not objects where there is an expectation that the items contained within can be reordered in respect to each other.

As such, there isn't anything built in that will order items contained in a `Tuple` - after all, if a tuple contains an integer, string, person object, order object and date, how would one order those?

You should be using a data structure that is built for holding items of the same type and which can be reasonably sorted - such as a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array from the tuple values. Sort the array.  Create a new tuple from the array.

```
var t = Tuple.Create(5, 4, 3, 3, 7, 8);

var arr = new int[] { t.Item1, t.Item2, t.Item3, t.Item4, t.Item5, t.Item6 };

Array.Sort(arr, (a, b) => b - a);

t = Tuple.Create(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
```

However, as already mentioned in other answers and comments, it looks like you're misusing the tuple.